# for a service that has a ​*lot*​ of video uploads, how do i chose between clojure v/s clojurescript + nodejs?

Tags: node.js, video, clojure, upload, clojurescript

I need to build a new system (service) from scratch that will talk with multiple frontends (web, mobile (android, iOs), etc) and will have majority of the time spent on video uploads

For the service, how do i decide between
1. clojure
2. clojurescript + node.js (since node.js is good for heavy IO)

Any general / specific pointers would be helpful

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any general / specific pointers would be helpful

Ok, here are a few:

1) Is the JVM available to your platform? If not, you can't use Clojure, so try ClojureScript.

2) How important is access to multithreading? Javascript is not multithreaded, and Clojurescript doesn't have multi-threaded core.async, agents, refs.

3) With heavy multimedia IO as you likely will need, what libraries are going to help you? I am sure you will not be doing all the low-level work yourself, you will leverage existing toolkits. Are those toolkits Java-based or Node/Js-based? If Java, use Clojure. If JS, use Clojurescript.

4) Mobile. Javascript is a more likely candidate for iOS since it is not a JVM platform (see my point 1 above). Some folks are successfully using Clojurescript on mobile.